# 'Can not create a Path from a null string' with hadoop -put command for csv

Tags: file, csv, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to pull in a basic csv file into hdfs

I am using this:

```
hadoop fs -put C:\Users\Desktop\Terrorism.csv /user/Mydata/terrorism.csv
```

Its giving me the following error:

```
 Can not create a Path from a null string
```

I could go the round about way by creating a hive table and loading the data into that table, but I simply want to put data onto hdfs.

Answer (score 2):

Use escaping on the path since it's Windows and uses backslashes :)

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Terrorism.csv /user/Mydata/terrorism.csv`

always a little nifty with the path escaping on windows but this way it works :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: @ShwetaKamble no problem:)

Comment: Changing it to this has cause another problem by this path escaping @ArminBraun. I get this error `unexpected URISyntaxException` I guess now there a whitespace in the path

Comment: @ShwetaKamble what does it say if you only add the `-copyFromLocal ` and do not add the extra escapes? so just
`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\Users\Desktop\Terrorism.csv /user/Mydata/terrorism.csv`

Comment: The same error as before  `Can not create a Path from a null string`

Comment: @ShwetaKamble ok so it seems we have to format the input path differently now on Windows ...
can you try `hadoop fs -put file:///c:/Users/Desktop/Terrorism.csv /user/Mydata/terrorism.csv` ?

Comment: @ShwetaKamble also try to run this from Desktop folder to rule out issues in your hdfs configuration so:
`hadoop fs -put Terrorism.csv /user/Mydata/terrorism.csv`

This should work either way.

Comment: We generally don't  provide the file_name in destination directory. @ShwetaKamble your command seems partially correct. Check if your HDFS is working or not. If it is working properly. then try `hadoop fs -put C:\Users\Desktop\Terrorism.csv /user/Mydata/`. You can check below Youtube  link for hadoop installation on windows for any possible error. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhxWig96dME